Mass retag [paging] to [memory-paging]
There is the paging tag which is about handling memory in a system. It is completely different to pagination which is about having some data (usually as a list) and splitting it into multiple pages. However, "paging" has been used where users wanted "pagination". Helped by the fact that the term "paging" is indeed synonym to "pagination".
I went through and re-tagged the incorrect usages of paging. However, more users will likely use it in the future. So, I propose mass retagging the paging to a more appropriate tag name like memory-paging (or anything else that will make it clear it is not the same as pagination).
The tag paging should most likely not be made a synonym to anything, but instead should be abandoned to not cause confusion in the future.

Mass retag == rename. Also that abandoned idea isn't good, as folks will recreate it. Unless someone keeps an eye on it continuously.

@BhargavRao but we (staff?) can  blacklist a tag, right?

Yep, but getting staff to blacklist tags isn't that easy.
